# How to fetch a specific data from a table and display that specific data in another page?

Tags: php, html

Hi there:) I have created a table where there's a list of  products.

```
if ($result) { 
    echo '<table align="center">
    <tr><th><b>ID</b></th><th><b>Name</b></th><th><b>Made_In</b> 
    </th><th><b>Price</b></th></tr>';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<tr><td >' . $row['ID'] . '</td>
        <td >' . $row['Name'] . '</td>
        <td >' . $row['Made_In'] . '</td>
        <td >' . $row['Price'] . '</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

Expected Output:

When the user want to see more details about this particular product, for example Product A. The user just have to click the product name and it will take the user to a new page where the user can see more details about the Product A such as description, ingredient, company's details etc.

Just so you know all of this is using the same table from the database called Product.

I have tried make the product's name as a link but i don't know how to fetch a specific data from the table to a new page.

I know this seems easy but i can't find the answer anywhere. Thank you for your time

Comment: So what do you need us to do? Write new code for free?  Are you asking how to write an html hyperlink with `id=$row['ID']`?  We need to code up the receiving code too? Seems **Too Broad**.

Comment: No, of course not. I just don't know where to  begin. My first idea is to create a link in the name but i don't know what to do after it got to a new page. I'm still new and dumb with web programming. :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
    if($result){?>
<table align="center">
    <tr><th><b>ID</b></th><th><b>Name</b></th><th><b>Made_In</b> 
    </th><th><b>Price</b></th></tr>


<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {?>
       <tr>
        <td ><a href="example.com/products/?id=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['ID'];?></a> </td>
        <td ><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
        <td ><?php echo $row['Made_In'];?></td>
        <td ><?php echo $row['Price'];?></td>
    </tr>
    }
<?php } ?>
```

you need to fetch the particular record in new page.

```
eg: $id = $_GET['id']; // this will receive from url eg: example.com/products?id=2
```

and fetch the records using that $id.
Now you can use show table with fetched detail.

Suggestion: you can use php inside html. So, its better to write html table tags and open/close php tags where necessary. This will make your code easier to understand.

Comment: You're assuming that the OP knows how to create that link to begin with. Looking at the question, there's no indication of that though.

Comment: well, there's always room to learn. I get the idea now thanks to Amrit. I don't ask for a full coding, just a guidance as I'm still a student.

Comment: No worries. Keep on learning. I was also a student once and know the feeling of getting stuck or not having an idea what to do next. Keep it up :)